# ReactJS + .Net Core WebApi 2.1 on IIS with Windows Authentication and SSL certificate

Tags: reactjs, ssl, iis, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have some issues with publishing react and web API on IIS with windows authentication. If you help I will be really appreciated. Let me explain first what I want;

- I have got 2 applications, one of them is reactjs and another one is core web API. I want to publish these applications on 2 different ports, port 3050 for react, port 3051 for web API. Also, I want to get domain user information in web API so I publish API with windows authentication. Besides all of them, I want to publish with SSL certificate. This is what I want.

Next, I want to explain my configuration on IIS;

- I built reactjs app on my local then I copied all files to the server. On IIS I created the application, created binding as type->https, port->3050, host name-> servername.domainname.com and I chose appropriate SSL certificate. I publish this app with Anonymous Authentication.
- I publish web API to Server. On IIS I created the application, created binding as type->https, port->3051, host name-> servername.domainname.com and I chose appropriate SSL certificate. I publish this app with Anonymous and Windows authentication. I also enabled anonymous because OPTION requests from reactjs give an error if I just enable windows authentication.

ISSUE: If I send request to server with writing whole servername (servername.domainname.com:3051) application always asks me to enter domain username and password. But if I send request to servername:3051 application works fine on chrome but it does not work on edge. Also in the second scenario browser gives certificate error, I think the server supposes that is insecure.

I want to ask if I did anything wrong on IIS configuration.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iis-cors-1-0 Preflight requests over Windows authentication is possible if you configure IIS CORS module.